# SQL query to return startdate and enddate

Tags: sql, join

I have a table as below:

```
ID Type StartDate  EndDate
1   A    20180401  20180420
2   A    20180402  20180420
3   B    20180403  20180420
4   C    20180404  20180420
5   C    20180405  20180420
6   A    20180406  20180420
7   A    20180407  20180420
8   A    20180408  20180420
9   A    20180409  20180420
10  A    20180410  20180420
```

I want to have a return something like :-

```
Type  StartDate   EndDate
A     20180401    20180402
B     20180403    20180403
C     20180404    20180405
A     20180406    20180420
```

Can anybody help with this query please.

Comment: can you put more details? This does not make sense

Comment: Thank you for sorting out my post format issue. Basically, this is a patient treatment chart. patient was admitted on 20180401 and discharged on 20180420. everyday, he has been given different type treatment. what I want to know is that each treatment start date and end date during the whole hospital stay.

Comment: If that is the case in the result that you need there is 20180402 as end date for type A but in your dataset this date is not there in end-date

Comment: no it's not. In the first table, endDate is the discharge date. only the last treatment will ended with discharge date. however before that the end date will be the same treatment start date.

Comment: it means that Type A have two days which are 20180401 and 20180402, and type B have one day 20180403, and so on...

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  I would use difference of row numbers:

```
select type, min(startdate), max(startdate)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by type order by id) as seqnum_1
      from t
     ) t
group by type, (seqnum - seqnum_1)
order by min(startdate);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you will see how the difference in row numbers identifies the adjacent rows with the same value.

Comment: you are a genius. it works perfectly. this is exactly what I want. thank you so much.